# R Configure Data With Data.Table

Tags: r, data.table, lead

```
data=data.frame("Student"=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5),
       "Grade"=c(5,6,7,3,4,5,4,5,6,8,9,10,2,3,4),
       "Pass"=c(NA,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,NA,NA,0,0,0),
       "NEWPass"=c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),
       "GradeNEWPass"=c(7,7,7,4,4,4,5,5,5,10,10,10,4,4,4),
       "GradeBeforeNEWPass"=c(6,6,6,3,3,3,4,4,4,10,10,10,4,4,4))
```

I have a data.frame called data. It has column names Student, Grade and Pass. I wish to do this:

NEWPass: Take Pass and for every Student fill in NA values with the previous value. If the first value is 'NA' than put a zero. Then this should be a running maximum.

GradeNEWPass: Take the lowest value of Grade that a Student got a one in NEWPass. If a Student did not get a one in NEWPass, this equals to the maximum grade.

GradeBeforeNEWPass: Take the value of Grade BEFORE a Student got a one in NEWPass. If a Student did not get a one in NEWPass, this equals to the maximum grade.

__
Attempts:

```
setDT(data)[, NEWPassTry := cummax(Pass), by = Student]
data$GradeNEWPass = data$NEWPassTry * data$Grade
data[, GradeNEWPass := min(GradeNEWPass), by = Student]
```

Comment: @akrun thank you do you have ideas for solution?

Comment: @akrun ok thank you, but they removed the answer.

Comment: Do you need `setDT(data)[, NewPass1 := cummax(+(Pass == 1 & !is.na(Pass))), Student];
 data[, GradeNEWPass1 := if(any(na.omit(Pass) == 1)) Grade[head(which(Pass == 1), 1)] else max(Grade, na.rm = TRUE), Student]`

Comment: @akrun i did not downvote you i selected your answer and gave you an upvote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213125/discussion-between-bvowe-and-akrun).

Comment: @akrun i am sorry that happened. your solution is perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table` methods.  Grouped by 'Student', create an index ('i1') where the 'Pass' is 1 and not an NA, then get the first position of 1 with `which` and `head` ('i2'), while calculating the `max` of 'Grade' ('mx'), then create the three columns based on the indexes ('v1' - get the cumulative maximum of the binary, 'v2' - `if` there are `any` 1s, then subset the 'Grade' with the index 'i2' or `else` return 'mx', similarly  'v3'- the index is subtracted 1 to get the 'Grade' value

```
library(data.table)    
setDT(data)[, c('NEWPass1', 'GradeNEWPass1', 'GradeBeforeNEWPass1') :={
              i1 <- Pass == 1 & !is.na(Pass)
              i2 <- head(which(i1), 1)
              mx <- max(Grade, na.rm = TRUE)
              v1 <- cummax(+(i1))
              v2 <- if(any(i1)) Grade[i2] else mx
              v3 <- if(any(i1)) Grade[max(1, i2-1)] else mx

            .(v1, v2, v3)}, Student]


data
#    Student Grade Pass NEWPass GradeNEWPass GradeBeforeNEWPass NEWPass1 GradeNEWPass1 GradeBeforeNEWPass1
# 1:       1     5   NA       0            7                  6        0             7                   6
# 2:       1     6    0       0            7                  6        0             7                   6
# 3:       1     7    1       1            7                  6        1             7                   6
# 4:       2     3    0       0            4                  3        0             4                   3
# 5:       2     4    1       1            4                  3        1             4                   3
# 6:       2     5    1       1            4                  3        1             4                   3
# 7:       3     4    0       0            5                  4        0             5                   4
# 8:       3     5    1       1            5                  4        1             5                   4
# 9:       3     6    0       1            5                  4        1             5                   4
#10:       4     8    0       0           10                 10        0            10                  10
#11:       4     9   NA       0           10                 10        0            10                  10
#12:       4    10   NA       0           10                 10        0            10                  10
#13:       5     2    0       0            4                  4        0             4                   4
#14:       5     3    0       0            4                  4        0             4                   4
#15:       5     4    0       0            4                  4        0             4                   4
```

Comment: yes i agree. @akrun gave a perfect solution to the post and I (the OP) selected it as the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, admittedly, but your logic includes words like *"if any ... for a student"*, so it's a group-wise conditional, not a row-wise conditional.

```r
library(magrittr) # just for %>% for breakout, not required
mydata %>%
  .[, NEWPass2 :=
        cummax(fifelse(seq_len(.N) == 1 & is.na(Pass), 0,
                       zoo::na.locf(Pass, na.rm = FALSE))), by = .(Student) ] %>%
  .[, GradeNEWPass2 :=
        if (any(NEWPass2 > 0)) min(Grade[ NEWPass2 > 0 ]) else max(Grade),
    by = .(Student) ] %>%
  .[, GradeBeforeNEWPass2 :=
        if (NEWPass2[1] == 0 && any(NEWPass2 > 0)) Grade[ which(NEWPass2 > 0)[1] - 1 ] else max(Grade),
    by = .(Student) ]
#     Student Grade Pass NEWPass GradeNEWPass GradeBeforeNEWPass NEWPass2 GradeNEWPass2 GradeBeforeNEWPass2
#  1:       1     5   NA       0            7                  6        0             7                   6
#  2:       1     6    0       0            7                  6        0             7                   6
#  3:       1     7    1       1            7                  6        1             7                   6
#  4:       2     3    0       0            4                  3        0             4                   3
#  5:       2     4    1       1            4                  3        1             4                   3
#  6:       2     5    1       1            4                  3        1             4                   3
#  7:       3     4    0       0            5                  4        0             5                   4
#  8:       3     5    1       1            5                  4        1             5                   4
#  9:       3     6    0       1            5                  4        1             5                   4
# 10:       4     8    0       0           10                 10        0            10                  10
# 11:       4     9   NA       0           10                 10        0            10                  10
# 12:       4    10   NA       0           10                 10        0            10                  10
# 13:       5     2    0       0            4                  4        0             4                   4
# 14:       5     3    0       0            4                  4        0             4                   4
# 15:       5     4    0       0            4                  4        0             4                   4
```

I'm using `magrittr::%>%` solely to break it out into stages of computation, it is not required.